# How to execute my confluent kafka Python producer and consumer code from local windows machine

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

```
from confluent_kafka
import Producer

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})# localhost has IP 
    address of the linux system


p.produce('topic', "Hello World!")
p.flush()
```

I ran the above code in my python idle windows and ran the zookeeper and kafka  in my companies unix system using putty. 
My program was running forever and I killed the execution.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is `from confluent_kafka import Producer` on a single line? Plz edit.

Comment: Yes its single line